# Getting JSON Exception While connecting GCM through curl

Tags: android, json, curl, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting an error when I make a curl request to GCM server:

`JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (m) at position 0`

`curl` request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: key=AIzaSyAuKLBnVEv_bm4fp88RqKaVm8DClzc" 
-X POST -d "message":"Hi I am Developer","registration_ids":"["APA91bGj-wkz4m6tEaFfual2HuRHNAn3CmAE6nRmv5LaOnuWa_6D3AnacqTmSCHXiKvdzINVc_XUGJhrXk0z5hQomdCM_9Nf6QqB-Pf9Q6Tf_DraUZZaUVtDiaRaIStgXsx0zMFqKJHU0q75OGCtq5OSGR11l3mCB5DBtzvl4nFwOws_UuA"]" 
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about GCM API, but I see the error. You don't send the valid JSON string and server can't parse it.

Wrap your data in curly braces. Replace

```
-d "message":"Hi I am Developer","registration_ids":"["APA91bGj-wkz4m6tEaFfual2HuRHNAn3CmAE6nRmv5LaOnuWa_6D3AnacqTmSCHXiKvdzINVc_XUGJhrXk0z5hQomdCM_9Nf6QqB-Pf9Q6Tf_DraUZZaUVtDiaRaIStgXsx0zMFqKJHU0q75OGCtq5OSGR11l3mCB5DBtzvl4nFwOws_UuA"]"
```

with

```
-d '{"message":"Hi I am Developer","registration_ids":"["APA91bGj-wkz4m6tEaFfual2HuRHNAn3CmAE6nRmv5LaOnuWa_6D3AnacqTmSCHXiKvdzINVc_XUGJhrXk0z5hQomdCM_9Nf6QqB-Pf9Q6Tf_DraUZZaUVtDiaRaIStgXsx0zMFqKJHU0q75OGCtq5OSGR11l3mCB5DBtzvl4nFwOws_UuA"]"}'
```